# How can I run my javascript tests in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

So my project's python portion has lots of helpful python tests to ensure the codebase isn't falling apart. I want to do the same for the javascript I'm serving out of my static directory.

Can anyone recommend strategies for testing my javascript, especially if it's wrapped into the django test running framework?

Comment: If it is or how it is to be integrated? What did you try? Did you even look for javascript unit testing libraries?

Comment: Apparently I wasn't clear enough: I want javascript unit testing that I can run from within Django.

Comment: How do you run your Python tests? It may not be possible to use the same command for the javascript tests.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup to Lettuce http://lettuce.it/. You can simulate a lot of browser's behavior to test your javascript.

Development in django http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html